# Get Imagesize in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the imagesize in jquery, I have this code.  It works to the point of

```
alert (v);
```

I wonder what is wrong with the rest when **v** actually contains a value.

```
 var v = $('#xxx input').val();
    alert (v);
    var newImg = new Image();
    newImg.src = v;
    var height = newImg.height;
    var width = newImg.width;
    alert ('The image size is '+width+'*'+height);
```

Thanks
Jean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code to get the image size won't always work. The image loads asynchronously, so the height and width will not be available immediately. You'll need something like the following:

```
var newImg = new Image();
var height, width;

newImg.onload = function() {
    height = newImg.height;
    width = newImg.width;
    window.alert('The image size is '+width+'*'+height);
};

newImg.src = v;
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming that #xxx is your input container id, your code should work :

```
<div id="xxx" align="center">
    <input name="test" value="/images/image1.jpg" />
</div>
```

**Update For Chrome**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var newImg = new Image();
    $(function() {
        var v = $('#xxx input').val();
        alert(v);
        newImg.src = v;
        setTimeout(function() {
            var height = newImg.height;
            var width = newImg.width;
            alert ('The image size is '+width+'*'+height);
        }, 1000);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: #xxx is the input field, the value is passed to var v and alerted too

Comment: checkout the updated script, should work on chrome, need to add delay, change it as you wish

Answer (score 0):

Are you receiving the correct URL to the image when you alert it?

My first idea would be to change the first line to:

```
var v = $('#xxx').val();
```

At the moment, you're selecting input elements **inside** an element with the ID of "xxx", but you want the element that **has** the ID "xxx".

**Edit:** another idea:

```
var v = $('#xxx input').val();
document.body.appendChild((function() {
    var newImg = document.createElement("img");
    newImg.src = v;
    newImg.id = "newImg";
    return newImg;
})());

var height = $("#newImg").attr("height");
var width = $("#newImg").attr("width");
alert('The image size is '+width+'*'+height);
```

Comment: I got the correct value for V and there is only one input field

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for the image to load!

```
var v = $('#xxx input').val();
alert (v);
var newImg = new Image();
newImg.onload = function() {
  var height = this.height;
  var width = this.width;
  alert ('The image size is '+width+'*'+height);
}
newImg.src = v;
```

EDIT: Moved the `src` assignment to the end.

Comment: 10 minutes to load an image? How big an image are we talking here? Or is it down to your connection speed?